# Add new file association in Windows 7 (Professional)

Tags: windows-7

I'm trying to associate ".bas" BASIC source files with QB64 (yes, I'm still playing with BASIC!). I successfully followed some guidelines I found in "stackoverflow.com," creating a new key in HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT, so now the files open in the desired program. However, I've been totally unsuccessful in assigning a default icon, even when adding a "DefaultIcon" key to the newly-created key for the file type, and pointing it toward the exact same source as for ".bat" files, located nearby in the registry. Any thoughts?

Comment: try this tool: http://defaultprogramseditor.com/

Comment: You might have to log off and log on to see the changes. Windows might not apply the icons immediately. Also a more powerful tool [filetypesman](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/file_types_manager.html). Provides a convenient UI to editing the registry